# Python Samba: user credentials not passed (cli_init_creds)?

Tags: python, windows, linux, authentication, samba

I am currently having a problem accessing Windows print shares (*at work, so I don't reall have access to their settings*) in Ubuntu, so I eventually got down to poking around the source of Gnome's '`system-config-printer`' which is written in Python, and uses the Python [`smbc`](http://packages.python.org/pysmbc/) bindings for Samba.

I have basically managed to get down my problem to this piece of code, which comes from `/usr/share/system-config-printer/pysmb.py`, and which I run in the `python` command line shell:

```
import smbc, os 
def do_auth (svr, shr, wg, un, pw):
  return ("myworkdomain.com", "MYWORKUSERNAME", "MYWORKPASSWORD")

ctx = smbc.Context (debug=10, auth_fn=do_auth)
f = ctx.open ("smb://%s/%s" % ("printserver.myworkdomain.com", "PRINTSHARENAME"), os.O_RDWR, 0777)
```

The first (sort of) a problem is that upon the execution of the `ctx = smbc.Context...` line, Python always complains:

```
params.c:OpenConfFile() - Unable to open configuration file "/home/MYUSERNAME/.smb/smb.conf":
    No such file or directory
```

... but maybe that is not really a problem? (maybe `smbc` *is* supposed to recreate this file anew?).

The big problem is, of course, that I cannot connect to the share: after executing the `f = ctx.open...` line, there is a big dump of Samba communication, Windows server seems to be talking etc - and the connection effort finishes with failure:

```
SPNEGO login failed: Logon failure
cli_init_creds: user  domain myworkdomain.com
 session setup ok
map_errno_from_nt_status: 32 bit codes: code=c0000022
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
smbc.PermissionError: (13, 'Permission denied')
```

Basically, I know too little about Samba to be able to read the rest of the error log, but I find the line:

```
cli_init_creds: user  domain myworkdomain.com
```

... very suspicious - it looks as if the '`user`' there is an empty string - even though I'd expect it to be '`MYWORKUSERNAME`', as specified by the '`do_auth`' function above!!

Note that this failure is somewhat similar to the `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE` that I used to get with the cmdline `smbclient` (see [Obtaining Windows printer share SMB settings (for tsclient/rdesktop on Linux) - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/326417/obtaining-windows-printer-share-smb-settings-for-tsclient-rdesktop-on-linux)), which was solved by explicity specifying a Windows workgroup on the command line - however, I cannot tell if that is also the problem here in the Python case; or if instead, the username is not passed here (or something completely third). EDIT: this working command line (which lists shares) is (in respect to this example):

```
smbclient -L \\printserver.myworkdomain.com -U MYWORKUSERNAME -W myworkdomain.com
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well, I think I finally got it, thanks to comments in [Bug #848065 “system-config-printer cannot authenticate Windows Samba printer, while smbclient can (cli_init_creds)”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/848065) - and reviewing [newprinter.py](http://geoservice.igac.gov.co/Ruteador/dz/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py) (from `system-config-printer`)...

But first of all, a little overview:

- My local username on my Ubuntu machine: `MYUSERNAME`
- Main address (domain) of the work network: `myworkdomain.com`
- My account name on the work network: `MYWORKUSERNAME`
- My work account is a member of workgroup `MYWORKGROUP`, which also has a subdomain `myworkgroup.myworkdomain.com`
- The print server on the work network is at `printserver.myworkdomain.com`
- The printer name (share) on the print server at work I want to access is `PRINTSHARENAME`

Well, it turns out that a single line in the `test.py` script above is wrong - instead of:

<s>`return ("myworkdomain.com", "MYWORKUSERNAME", "MYWORKPASSWORD")`</s>

... one should have had:

`return ("MYWORKGROUP", "MYWORKUSERNAME", "MYWORKPASSWORD")`

... (with `MYWORKGROUP` in allcaps, as typical for Windows)

Interestingly, using the workgroup subdomain *does not* work:

<s>`return ("myworkgroup.myworkdomain.com", "MYWORKUSERNAME", "MYWORKPASSWORD")`</s>

... as it will also fail with '`smbc.PermissionError: (13, 'Permission denied')`' (just like the original post example).

One way to troubleshoot the "permission denied" error is to check the log - it shows something like this:

```
    DomainNameLen            : 0x000c (12)
    DomainNameMaxLen         : 0x000c (12)
    DomainName               : *
        DomainName               : 'myworkdomain.com'
    UserNameLen              : 0x0004 (4)
    UserNameMaxLen           : 0x0004 (4)
    UserName                 : *
        UserName                 : 'MYWORKUSERNAME'
    WorkstationLen           : 0x0012 (18)
    WorkstationMaxLen        : 0x0012 (18)
    Workstation              : *
        Workstation              : 'MYPC'
```

... apparently, the DomainName should be:

```
        DomainName               : 'MYWORKGROUP'
```

For reference, here is a snippet of the log from the "working" setup (with `return ("MYWORKGROUP" ...`):

```
...
cli_init_creds: user MYWORKUSERNAME domain MYWORKGROUP
 session setup ok
 tconx ok
...
Could not retrieve case sensitivity flag: NT_STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST.
Server connect ok: //printserver.myworkdomain.com/PRINTSHARENAME: 0xa297768
Performing aggressive shutdown.
...
smbc_remove_usused_server: 0xa297768 removed.
Context 0xa276658 successfully freed
```